# Facebook sdk iOS pictures returning from request as nil

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

So in the app I took over everything was loading fine from Facebook, before I submitted to the app store. Then I was not able to validate with the Facebook app. So I decided to force the users to use the dialog by commenting out some stuff in Facebook.m. The previous developer did not include any of the .m files and was using an older sdk version with a .a file included. So I decided to use the newer sdk version and included all of the .m files. Problem now is that in the app the following behavior takes place:

```
 [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
```

Successfully loads the username (when logged in of course) and:

```
 [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/home" andDelegate:self];
```

Successfully loads the feed item data.

However,

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/picture?type=normal", facebookFeedItem.fromId];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:path andDelegate:self];
```

Where fromId is the id of the user returns a successful request but a nil value for the photo data.

So does:

```
 NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/picture", feedItem.objectIdentifier];
 [facebook requestWithGraphPath:path andDelegate:self];
```

Did something change in versions that would effect this or am I looking at some other internal problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and concluded that it's a problem with Facebook's implementation of either the SDK or something server side. The way to get pictures is to use an FQL query, this then returns the data as expected, and in fact gives you much more control over what data you want back. It's pretty similar to doing an SQL select statement (and doesn't really get very complicated, so it's easy to pick up if you're new to it..)

docs here : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

your code would be something like this (for the logged in users profile picture for example):

```
    NSString *fqlStatementForProfilePicture = @"SELECT pic FROM user WHERE uid=me()";

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               fqlStatementForProfilePicture, @"query",nil];

    FBRequest *theRequest = [facebook requestWithMethodName:@"fql.query"
                                 andParams:params
                             andHttpMethod:@"GET"
                               andDelegate:self];
```

from here on the delegate callsbacks behave in exactly the same way as requests made with `[facebook requestWithGraphPath.....]`

Comment: Hmm.. This works but seems to return a dictionary that has a url string of the photo.. is this expected?